# Visual Studio 2008 Express C++ 32 bit build on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, 32bit-64bit

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Express. I have a solution which used to work fine on Vista 32 bit. I recently switched over to Windows 7, and part of it stopped working. This is my setup:
- Unmanaged C++ static library, "the library"
- Managed C++ DLL that wraps functionality of "the library" for use in C#, "the DLL"
- Managed C++ console application that references "the DLL"
- C# application that references "the DLL"

I am getting an exception thrown by the DLL when running the C# application, and I usually debug problems like that through the managed C++ console app, since I can then step into the unmanaged library code.

The problem is that I now get a popup dialog with some weird symbols and the path to *"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\dw20.exe"*, and then my app catches an exception *"System.BadImageFormatException:  is not a valid Win32 application"* thrown when I try to run the managed C++ console app. I have spent a lot of time researching this issue, and anything that even remotely resembles useful advice refers to building X86 projects in C#, but nothing about C++. I tried adding */MACHINE:X86* to the Librarian options of the library, but that doesn't seem to work.

I guess in short my question is, how do I get to make sure my unmanaged C++ static library builds so that it can run on 32 bit systems?

Answer (score 4):

The dw20.exe program is "Doctor Watson", the program that reports unhandled runtime exceptions and crashes.  Not the source of the problem, merely the messenger.  Although unstated in the question, I have to assume your Windows 7 version is 64-bit, the common source of System.BadImageFormatException.

The exception is caused by a 64-bit process trying to load a DLL that was built for 32-bit.  Or the other way around, a 32-bit process cannot load a 64-bit DLL.  The bitness of the process is determined by the EXE, a C++/CLI app in your case.  It doesn't have the option to change it with a simple project setting, like C# projects do.  You do it by adding a platform, "x64" uses the 64-bit compiler and generates a 64-bit executable.  I'm pretty sure that is not available in the C++ Express edition though, you don't have the 64-bit compilers so must always generate a 32-bit executable.

Which leaves very little room to explain the exception.  It could only go wrong if you changed the Platform target setting in your C# class library project.  From x86 or AnyCPU to x64.  Change it back to AnyCPU.  Project + Properties, Build tab.  If you have done anything to hack around the limitations of the Express edition, like adding 64-bit compilers from an SDK release then that would be a major red flag for the source of the problem as well.

Comment: Indeed, I am on Windows 7 64 bit. I didn't realize there is a 32 bit version.So the weird thing is, my C# application is working, it's the C++/CLI console app that is giving me this. It is set to target MachineX86. I guess I should mention it was working for a while, then went to hell when I had to uninstall Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (which messes with the ADO type libraries).

Comment: Well, you have a cause-and-effect.  How that affects your code is completely unguessable from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Change the built from Any CPU to 32 or 86, and you should have no problem. you probably are using in the c++ code a windows 32 dll  that's why it doesn't work on other platforms.
Any CPU-> configuration Manager then change to 32 or 86

Comment: There is no option like that in C++, only in C#. The only build available is Win32.